# Copy elision with std::mutex

Tags: c++, mutex, copy-elision

[This explanation of copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) states that

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit
>   the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move
>   constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The
>   objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would
>   otherwise be copied/moved to. The copy/move constructors need not be
>   present or accessible, as the language rules ensure that no copy/move
>   operation takes place, even conceptually:
>
> In a return statement, when the operand is a prvalue of the same class
>   type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type:
>
> T f() { return T(); }
>   f(); // only one call to default constructor of T

My question is why does the following code not compile then:

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex createMutex()
{
    return std::mutex();
}

int main()
{
    auto mutex = createMutex();
}
```

[Example program with compile errors.](https://onlinegdb.com/HyLxpdASH)

Comment: mutex as return value? WAT? You are doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: @MarekR I don't think so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My question is why does the following code not compile then

Because the reference that you quote says

> **(since C++17)**

It does not apply to older C++ standards. You compiled the program with a C++14 compiler. In C++14, the returned object is moved, so the type must be movable, which `std::mutex` is not. The move *may* be elided as an optimisation, but that possibility does not remove the movability requirement.

The example is well-formed in C++17 and will compile using a compliant compiler.

Comment: @StaceyGirl I still had the timeout at the time I wrote my comment. Ofc I will accpet a good answer!